# Conexion mysqli procedimental

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy migrando una aplicación antigua de mysql a mysqli. La conexión se crea en un archivo de configuración y luego se usa esa conexión en toda la aplicación. Para ello se guardaba la conexión en una constante y se usaba posteriormente para ejecutar las consultas. Pero con mysqli veo que si guardo la conexión en una constante luego no me ejecuta las consultas.

La conexión se crea así y se guarda en una constante:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(BD_HOST, BD_USUARIO, BD_PASSWORD,BD_BD);
mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');
define("CON", $con);
```

Si intento hacer una consulta usando la constante no funciona:

```
    $exec_id_transmisiones =  mysqli_query(CON,"SELECT * FROM colores  in (1,2,3)");
```

Pero si lo hago usando la variable local si.

```
    $exec_id_transmisiones =  mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM colores  in (1,2,3)");
```

El problema es que necesito acceder a la conexión desde otras paginas, pero al no poder hacerlo mediante la constante no se que solucione seria la mejor. Tampoco comprendo como con mysql si podía usar dicha constante para la conexión y ahora no...

Gracias!

Comment: No veo mucha diferencia, simplemente establece la variable $con donde antes tenias el `define` y sustitúyelo en las consultas. Lo digo por el ámbito, deberia ser el mismo.

Comment: Según [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56324956/1545868) (en inglés) parece no es posible guardar una conexión mysql en una constante. Sugiero reescribir toda la parte mysql, pero si no es una opción, entonces algo casi transparente -que no es buena práctica (pero para resolver)- es dejándola como variable y llamándola dentro de las funciones como [variable global](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php) `global $con;`

Answer (score 3):

Según la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.define.php):

> El valor de la constante. En PHP 5, value debe ser un valor scalar (integer, float, string, boolean, o null). En PHP 7, también se aceptan valores de tipo array.

Y hay que tomar nota de esto:

> **Advertencia** Aunque es posible definir constantes de tipo resource, no se recomienda debido a que podría causar un comportamiento impredecible.

Desconozco si te funcionaba anteriormente por la versión de PHP o el tipo de recurso, pero, como ves, no es recomendable.

En cuanto a las opciones, ya te sugirieron una en comentarios, pero podría complicar un poco la actualización de tus scripts que, de hecho, deberías migrar a objetos. Sin embargo, para tratar de facilitar las cosas, puedes crear una función en el archivo de configuración que devuelva la conexión:

```
// Conectas como lo haces normalmente
$con = mysqli_connect(BD_HOST, BD_USUARIO, BD_PASSWORD,BD_BD);
mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');
// En vez de definir la constante, crea una función
function CON() {
    global $con;
    return $con;
}
```

Después, cada que necesites la conexión, la obtienes por medio de la función:

```
$exec_id_transmisiones =  mysqli_query(CON(),"SELECT * FROM colores  in (1,2,3)");
```

Esto te permitiría remplazar desde tu entorno de desarrollo todas las coincidencias de `CON` por `CON()`, especificando que deben coincidir mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Por ejemplo, en Visual Studio Code, presionas [CTRL][Shift][H] y marcas la opción `Aa` para buscar solo coincidencias de mayúsculas y minúsculas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego aplicas el remplazo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Importante:** Esto es solo una opción para *"corregir"* tu problema actual, pero lo recomendable es migrar a programación orientada a objetos.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por vuestras respuestas. Finalmente he creado una clase singleton que me devuelve la conexión, esta solución ha sido bastante buena, teniendo en cuenta la estructura del proyecto.

```
class Connection{

  private static $con;

  private static $db_host = BD_HOST;
  private static $db_name = BD_BD;
  private static $db_username = BD_USUARIO ;
  private static $db_password = BD_PASSWORD;

  static public function mx() {
    if (self::$con === null) {
      self::$con =  mysqli_connect(self::$db_host, self::$db_username, self::$db_password,self::$db_name);
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Falló la conexión2: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
      }
      mysqli_set_charset(self::$con ,'utf8');
    }

    return self::$con; 
  }
}
```